# reshaping/transforming results in a column to remove some values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want the results under the aliased column ReimMethod to be transformed.

Currently the result set contains `QTP Driect Deposit` and `Check DD`. I'd like them to be converted to `Direct Deposit` and `Check` respectively.

```
 (SELECT rc.name from ReimbursementChoice rc 
  WHERE rc.admin_id = a.admin_id AND rc.choice_id = pe.payment_choice) 
  AS 'ReimMethod',
```

How can this be done? Should I use `CASE` or `Convert` to perform the required action?

[image]

Comment: Convert doesn't do that.  use CASE or REPLACE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could solve your problem but then I don't think it's the best thing to do. You would need to process data in your main program rather then requesting it by query. It would be better practice

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(rc.name,'QPT ',''), ' DD','') FROM ...
```

You might consider to use regular expressions as well